# Como implementar a ActionBar fixada em baixo, da versão android 2.x ou maior?

Tags: java, android

Estou implementando Action Bar em android da versão 2.x ou maior, entretanto, estou com dificuldades com relação à forma de exibição dos elementos. Na versão 2.x  a barra aparece em baixo, só que sem os nomes dos menus, e na versão 3.0 ou maior a action bar está alinhada no topo. Quero que a action bar fique alinhada em baixo, com os nomes dos menus tanta na versão 2.x quanto nas outras.
  Estou utilizando a classe de suport da action bar `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`

```
package com.lucas;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // inflate the layout, etc...
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Titulo");
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icont);
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Subtitulo");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.phone:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.computer:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Computer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.gamepad:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Gamepad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.camera:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.video:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.email:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected EMail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        return true;
    }

}
```

xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:icon="@drawable/phone"
        android:title="@string/phone"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/computer"
        android:icon="@drawable/computer"
        android:title="@string/computer"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/gamepad"
        android:icon="@drawable/gamepad"
        android:title="@string/gamepad"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/camera"
        android:title="@string/camera"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:icon="@drawable/video"
        android:title="@string/video"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:icon="@drawable/email"
        android:title="@string/email"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

</menu>
```

Manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lucas"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <!--  <android:hardwareAccelerated="true"  -->

        <activity android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Como implementar a ActionBar de forma que ele fique em baixo e com o nome dos ícones, da versão 2.x ou maior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro algumas considerações: Tenha em mente de que uma ActionBar tem seu lugar bem definido pelas Guide Lines (recomendações) do Google. Este lugar é a parte de cima da tela. Qualquer coisa que você fizer fora dali não é uma ActionBar.

A ActionBar foi criado na versão Honycomb (3.0) e com elas os menus das versões anteriores foram removidos (menus com ícones e nomes na parte de baixo). Ou seja, se você quer uma ActionBar, utilizando a classe `ActionBarActivity` ela ficará na parte de cima, pois é o lugar dela.

Mas se você quer os menus com ícones e nomes na parte de baixo que existiam nas versões Ginberbread e abaixo(2.3), terá que implementar um menu normalmente (sem suporte e sem ActionBar) e mudar a propriedade `targetSdkVersion` para  no máximo 10, **o que altamente NÃO recomendado**, pois você perderá todos os recursos dos novos aparelhos (além que ficar com esse layout tosco e ultrapassado dos aparelhos antigos).

Answer (score 1):

Eu já tive diversos problemas com a `actionbar` nos meus projetos para 2.x que usavam `sherlock` (sei que não é seu caso) então decide eu mesmo criar uma `view` que fazia a mesma coisa. Depois eu desativei a `actionbar` colocando lá no `AndroidManisfest` (Voce pode desativar programaticamente também).

Comment: Hum entendo Othon, eu tentei usar a compatibilidade da Sherlock também, mas ficava ainda pior o resultado..

Comment: a actionbar do sherlock não permite que voce use o layout muito bem. É um bug de implementação deles mesmo! Melhor você fazer sua própria view

Comment: Othon vc teria algum material, algo que me desse uma visao de como criar a minha própria view?

Answer (score 1):

Como foi dito na resposta anterior, existem guidelines que especificam a posição exacta do ActionBar.
A aplicação sempre que correr em dispositivos com uma tela menor tentara diminuir os itens e os nomes no actionbar para que se possa poupar espaço e colocara todos os items que nao tem alta prioridade no "overflow". Mas você pode usar o Split Actionbar que ira criar uma actionbar em cima e outra em baixo caso você esteja em um dispositivo com tela pequena e colocara todos itens em cima em dispositivos como tablets que o espaço na actionbar e bem maior.
Para fazer isso basta colocar no manifest:

```
<manifest ...>
<activity uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" ... >
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
               android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
</activity>
```